# Resque queue: No live threads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, carrierwave, resque, minimagick

I have been trying to get a resque task running.  Resque seems to be enqueueing and running tasks; however, tasks seem to be "deadlocking" often upon execution.

A sample error is as follows:  (taken from the Resque::Failure output)

```
 {"failed_at"=>"2015/07/20 22:34:46 UTC",
  "payload"=>{"class"=>"ImportHawaiiEventsOnline", "args"=>[]},
  "exception"=>"fatal",
  "error"=>"No live threads left. Deadlock?",
"backtrace"=>
   ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:262:in `value'",
    "/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:262:in `block in capture3'",
    "/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:199:in `popen_run'",
    "/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:93:in `popen3'",
    "/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:252:in `capture3'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/shell.rb:47:in `execute_open3'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/shell.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in execute'",
    "/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/shell.rb:35:in `block in execute'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/logger.rb:32:in `call'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/logger.rb:32:in `block in benchmark'",
    "/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/logger.rb:32:in `benchmark'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/logger.rb:21:in `debug'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/shell.rb:34:in `execute'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/shell.rb:18:in `run'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:92:in `call'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:53:in `new'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:477:in `identify'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:198:in `validate!'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:113:in `block in create'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:112:in `tap'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:112:in `create'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:34:in `read'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:90:in `block in open'",
    "/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'",
    "/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.7/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:89:in `open'",
    "/srv/releases/4/app/uploaders/photo_uploader.rb:57:in `get_geometry'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:84:in `block in process!'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `each'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `process!'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:122:in `cache!'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/download.rb:72:in `download!'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:356:in `remote_url='",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:187:in `remote_photo_url='",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:45:in `remote_photo_url='",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `public_send'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'",
    "/srv/releases/4/event_jobs/generic_import.rb:45:in `event_endpoint'",
    "/srv/releases/4/event_jobs/generic_import.rb:113:in `save_event'",
    "/srv/releases/4/event_jobs/hawaiieventonline/import.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in get_parser'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'",
    "/srv/releases/4/event_jobs/hawaiieventonline/import.rb:24:in `each_with_index'",
    "/srv/releases/4/event_jobs/hawaiieventonline/import.rb:24:in `block in     get_parser'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'",
    "/srv/releases/4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'",
    "/srv/releases/4/event_jobs/hawaiieventonline/import.rb:21:in `get_parser'",
    "/srv/releases/4/event_jobs/generic_import.rb:22:in `run_parse'",
    "/srv/releases/4/app/jobs/import_hawaiieventsonline.rb:17:in `perform'"],
  "worker"=>
   "be920dfe9b17:5637:`(queues)`",
  "queue"=>"`(queue)`"},
```

I was guessing it had to do with the mini_magick gem - though it seems odd that it would suggest a deadlock since I'm only running one thread.  I would guess its possibly due the sheer amount of requests being made asynchronously - though I don't fully understand the mini_magick and carrierwave gems.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to look to resolve this thread issue?  I am running 17 queues with one worker thread handling all of these queues at the moment, and it seems to run fine - just that there may be an issue with saving to the cloud.  Trying to search for anything related to mini_magick/carrierwave and a thread issue seems to not show anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just hit a very similar error myself - did you find the root cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, are you running Resque-Pool or any other forking/threading in your code?  MiniMagick uses open3 to run shell commands, and it apparently has a [reputation](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/63) for not playing nice with threads.  Luckily, MiniMagick allows you to swap out open3 for [Posix-Spawn](https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn).

I was getting the same error using threaded workers (Resque-Pool jobs) and switching to Posix-Spawn appears to have resolved the error for me.